# Adding an icon to content & handling its events

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to use this code but i dont know the exact class for google search results that would replace "the_search_result_class". Please help me to find out Dom class for google search results on google search page.

```
function someFunction() {
    alert("The user clicked on the icon.")
}

var icon = document.createElement("img");
icon.src = chrome.extension.getURL("icon.png");
var searchResults = document.getElementsByClassName("the_search_result_class")
for (var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
    var searchResultIcon = icon.cloneNode();
    searchResultIcon.addEventListener("click", someFunction, false);
    searchResults[i].append(searchResultIcon);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To find out a dynamic class name on a page:

1. Open developer console (Ctrl+Shift+J)
2. Click on "Elements" tab and then on the magnifying glass icon
3. Select element you are interested in on a page and you will see its html source below.